# Including a source file

Tags: c

So I want to commit the sin of including source files in source files.

Essentially I am constructing a universal main.c file, it will be the base for any project I make on this platform.

Project to project the only real difference in my main.c file is in the main function itself.

What I want to do is create another file, projectloop.c, and have that file included in place of the main function. Having it behave like text insertion.

```
//main.c:
#include "main.h"
...// includes
...// standard functions

int main(void) {
   ...// standard configuration

   #include "projectloop.c"
}
```

However I'm not sure what I can put inside the projectloop.c file to get it to compile.

I'd like it to be as simple as

```
//projectloop.c:
while(1) {
    // do my project loop
    ledOn();
    delay();
    ledOff();
    delay();
}
```

This won't build though.

I get an error on the first line of projectloop.c "Expected a declaration".

I have two questions.

1. Can I do direct text insertion with C the way I'm trying to do it?
2. Is there a good reason not to structure my code this way?

I haven't really worked with #including source files directly, I was under the impression that it would simply replace the #include statement with the file contents.

---

Update: I didn't mention previously that I was attempting to do this in the Eclipse environment.

When I was using the Eclipse 'build' command, the projectloop.c file was getting built on it's own.

Right clicking on projectloop.c in the Eclipse project explorer I was able to select "Exclude from Build"

Comment: Well, if the compiler is still trying to build projectloop.c as a standalone compilation unit, it's probably not goint to work.

Comment: Unless you are guarding it against double inclusion.. But then the result would depend on the compilation order.

Comment: If you are including projectloop.c into main(), then don't compile projectloop.c as a standalone file.  Is there any reason you can't just have main call a function such as `mainLoop();` and define that function somewhere else?

Comment: You can only call functions that have already been declared, so in your main file, include a header that declares `ledOn`, `delay`, etc.

Comment: I remain to be convinced that what you're trying is a good idea (it probably isn't), but it should work as long as you're careful.  One part of being careful will be not compiling `projectloop.c` as a standalone file.  As to why it is a bad idea: one reason is that you will end up with different copies of `projectloop.c` -- one per program built using this style.  If you're going to do (I'm still not convinced), then `#ifndef PROJECTLOOP_SOURCE` `#error PROJECTLOOP_SOURCE not defined` `#endif` `#include PROJECTLOOP_SOURCE`, and then make sure you specify the correct name in the build process.

Comment: 1. You can, 2. Too many to list in the space of this comment 3. #including works the way you think, replacing the #include statement with the file contents.  But **Why do you want to do this?**

Comment: @tux3, JS1: I wondered if that was the issue. I will see if I can get Eclipse not to compile that file on it's own

Comment: @chqrlie The idea is that I can have an easily maintainable main.c file. If I update my main.c in a way suitable for all projects, I can copy and paste it into the other existing projects without overwriting the project specific code.

Comment: @user3817250 If it is hard to get Eclipse to do that, just rename it to projectloop.h because the name of the file doesn't really matter.  But I still suggest that you don't do this.

Comment: I `#include` other source files in the main source file because I don't use IDE, and to keep the MAKEFILE simple, and because modern compilers and computers are blindingly quick anyway. But I don't put them "inline".

Comment: If fiddling with Eclipse settings ends up being the answer, please edit the question to include the fact that you couldn't build in eclipse.

Comment: @user3817250: separating the body from the definition of the `main` function is not a good idea.  You will gain nothing from that, just aggravation with tools that won't support your *non standard* source convention.  There is usually not much in the main project file that is not project specific.  Bending the rules this way to not duplicate copyright notices seems vain.  Furthermore, if the name of the included project file differs from one project to another, you will still need to duplicate the main project file, thereby defeating the purpose.

Answer (score 0):

As far as i know (or remember), standard **C** has no feature to make a **.c** or **.h** file a template since this is what you need, a **template.c** file which can generate multiple different sources depending on parameters.

Maybe using a custom script (even a [bash script using sed](http://linux.about.com/od/commands/l/blcmdl1_sed.htm)) would be the best option.

Eg.

**main.c.tpl** file

```
//main.c:
#include "main.h"
...// includes
...// standard functions

int main(void) {
   ...// standard configuration

   %%MAIN_CODE%%
}
```

Then use the script to read the **main.c.tpl** file and replace the %%MAIN_CODE%% tag with any text or source code from another file (or whatever) and dump the output into the actual **main.c** file for the current project which will actually be compiled

Comment: The preprocessor can do this and include a file specified as `-DFILENAME=filename` on the command line.  It is a bit cumbersome but possible.  But **not advisable**.

Comment: @chqrlie, yes of course but how can you instruct the CPP to add the file contents in a specific place in the code? i;m not sure

Comment: @chqrlie, maybe using a preprocessor macro instead of %%MAIN_CODE%% in  my example, hmm yes this would work, provided the MAIN_CODE macro in the included file is passed as parameter. Yet as far as i remeber CPP macros **cannot** span more than one line of code, so it would be limited

Comment: I was hinting to use a `#include FILENAME` instead of the ugly shell tag.  But this discussion is giving me a headache.  Don't do this, don't try to fix it, learn more C before you start bending the rules.

Answer (score 0):

I've never seen it done that way.

Usually people will pass `int argc, char* argv[]` from main, into their own code module, where all the magic happens.

```
#include "myModule.h"

int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {

    myModule(argc, argv);    

    return 0;
}
```